# URL Encoding issues - with decimals

Tags: javascript, encoding, escaping, decimal

http://jsfiddle.net/3u4hn/1/

I have added the comments in the code for each function what I am trying to achieve here.
I am using `escape` to match the value in url (where it will be encoded.) I am able to handle all the values except the values with decimals. For example if I have:

`var s = "9%252E5|red|blue";
var itemToRemove = escape("9.5"); //escape to match the value in 's'.`

As '.' can not be encoded/escaped I am not able to match the one with url, any ideas on how to deal this kind of an issue.

Comment: The `.` character has no special meaning in URLs, it doesn't need to be escaped. What's the problem you're having with it? Also, you shouldn't use the obsolete function `escape`, use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Yes, '.' can not be handled this way, but I am not sure how should I match the item with decimal as in URL it is encoded.

Comment: decodeURIComponent, then match

Comment: Match in what way? Please show the code you're having trouble with? Are you trying to use it in a regular expression? You need to put `\ ` before `.` in regular expressions.

Comment: the two functions are in my fiddle.

Comment: @ dandavis: tried that, but once I decode, it becomes 9.5 and now when putting back in url I cant put a encoded value again because it is a decimal again... grab an element from some other event (9.5) and search for it in url (where it is encoded) and then remove it and re-arrange the URL - this is the requirement.

Comment: +1 to dandavis's advice.  You might also want to familiarize yourself with [arguments against `escape`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)